# MLR: Extracting the names of the covariates with non-zero coefficients in CoxBoost

Tags: r, machine-learning, cox-regression, mlr

I am using mlr to create a survival model with the learner cv.CoxBoost and 5-fold cross-validation. (Yes I realise cv.CoxBosst has CV built in, but I am adding another level to be consistent with the other learners I am comparing it against). I need to extract the names of the covariates with nonzero coefficients from the final model, as you would do if you were using Lasso. However, I only seem to be able to get the output from the individual runs of CoxBoost, not from cv.CoxBoost.

This is what I have tried:

```
library(survival)
library(mlr)
set.seed(24601)
data(veteran)

task_id = "MAS_MEDEXAM"
surv.task <- makeSurvTask(id = task_id, data = veteran, target = c("time", "status"))

cindex.sd = setAggregation(cindex, test.sd)
surv.measures = list(cindex, cindex.sd)

cboostcv.lrn <- makeLearner(cl="surv.cv.CoxBoost", id = "CoxBoostCV", predict.type="response")

outer = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters=5, stratify=TRUE)
learners = list(cboostcv.lrn)
bmr = benchmark(learners, surv.task, outer, surv.measures, show.info = TRUE)

mods = getBMRModels(bmr, learner.ids = c('CoxBoostCV'))
mod = mods$MAS$CoxBoostCV[[1]]$learner.model
str(mod, max.level=1)
```

Which produced the following output:

```
List of 16
 $ time            : num [1:109] 87 123 182 97 83 100 103 164 30 10 ...
 $ status          : num [1:109] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ stepno          : num 43
 $ penalty         : num [1:9] 918 918 918 918 918 918 918 918 918
 $ xnames          : chr [1:9] "trt" "karno" "diagtime" "age" ...
 $ n               : int 109
 $ p               : int 9
 $ event.times     : num [1:81] 1 2 3 4 7 8 10 11 12 13 ...
 $ coefficients    :Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
 $ linear.predictor: num [1:44, 1:109] 0 -0.0607 -0.1171 -0.1695 -0.218 ...
 $ meanx           : num [1:9] 1.49 57.24 8.95 58.41 3.03 ...
 $ sdx             : num [1:9] 0.502 20.489 11.31 10.768 4.616 ...
 $ standardize     : logi TRUE
 $ Lambda          : num [1:44, 1:81] 0.0184 0.0184 0.0183 0.0182 0.0181 ...
 $ scoremat        : num [1:43, 1:9] 0.0404 0.0503 0.0604 0.0704 0.0802 ...
 $ logplik         : num -357
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "CoxBoost"
 - attr(*, "mlr.train.info")=List of 5
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "FixDataInfo"
```

This is consistent with output from CoxBoost, but cv.CoxBoost is supposed to return the following:

```
mean.logplik
se.logplik
optimal.step
folds
```

How do I extract this information?

**EDIT:** 
After contacting Prof Harald Binder and examining the mlr code for the cv.CoxBoost learner I realised that I had misunderstood its operation. Prof Binder's response was

`cv.CoxBoost only determines the number of boosting steps to be performed. You have to fit a model (using a CoxBoost call) afterwards, using that number of steps.`

The mlr learner cv.CoxBoost does exactly that - it first calls cv.CoxBoost to find the optinal number of steps, then calls CoxBoost using that number of steps.

So my question now is, will the following code give me the names of the covariates with non-zero coefficients in the final model?

```
mods = getBMRModels(bmr, learner.ids = c('CoxBoostCV'))
for (i in 1:5) {
    mod = mods[[task_id]]$CoxBoostCV[[i]]$learner.model
    print(mod$xnames[mod$coefficients[mod$stepno+1,] != 0])
}
```

Comment: Why is it supposed to "return the following"?
You can see the standard parameter settings in mlr here: https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/blob/master/R/RLearner_surv_cv.CoxBoost.R

Comment: Thanks @PhilippPro. I misunderstood the operation of cv.CoxBoost. Please see edit above.